# Can I write a type guard that throws exceptions instead of returning booleans?

Tags: typescript, nullable, assertions

I have a class that uses the same type guard in multiple functions; something like this:

```
function validData(d: Data | null): d is Data {
    return d !== null;
}

class C {
    data: Data | null;

    public doA() {
        if (!validData(this.data))
            throw new Error("Invalid data");
        /* … */
    }

    public doB() {
        if (!validData(this.data))
            throw new Error("Invalid data");
        /* … */
    }
}
```

Can I refactor this code to move the error into the type guard?  Something like this:

```
function assertData(d: Data | null): ??? {
    if (d === null)
        throw new Error("Invalid data");
}
```

…which I could use like this:

```
class C {
    data: Data | null;

    public doA() {
        assertData(this.data);
        /* … */
    }

    public doB() {
        assertData(this.data);
        /* … */
    }
}
```

Currently I'm using the following workaround:

```
function must(d: Data | null): Data {
    if (d === null)
        throw new Error("Invalid data");
    return d;
}
```

… but this forces me to wrap every access to `this.data` in `must()`.

Comment: Would be useful, but current syntax does not support this as far as I know.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir That sounds like a proper answer; I'd be happy to accept it in a few days if you post it :)

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer because if I do people will be less inclined to look at the question, and I hope someone will look at this and find a magical solution ;)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir there is no magical solution I know. Feel free to add as answer 

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Edit**
Since the original answer, typescript has added the ability for custom type assertions in [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695)

```
type Data = { foo: string };

function assertData(d: Data | null): asserts d is Data {
    if (d == null)
        throw new Error("Invalid data");
}
// Use
declare var bar: Data | null;
bar.foo // error as expected
assertData(bar)
bar.foo // inferred to be Data
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeUBmB7bAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMoBfAbgChHMBXCgY2DOwqjkKEIJYPEQAKACYExSAD5QKrADbKAlAQFCRhKJKhlds9IyhmDmKFJSolqtafNPgACxLYA7ooheAoiXcScQAiAEkKADc4ZTJ9SQQ4YLUmWkYAejSoAFUhRkkIDmU4EmgokigAI2KZBKgFO2UmKpIAOhxsKAyoYUD+XQgAD0guCElGLWFRBPFmh2a23E7Mykwe0ahgDoroWUYgA)

**Original answer**

Unfortunately the current syntax for type guards requires an `if` statement for them to work. So this works

```
type Data = { foo: string };
function assertData(d: Data | null): d is Data {
    if (d == null)
        throw new Error("Invalid data");
    return true;
}
// Use
let bar: Data | null = null;
if (assertData(bar)) {
    bar.foo // inferred to be Data
}
```

But there is no way to get this to work:

```
let bar: Data | null = null;
assertData(bar);
bar.foo // bar will still be Data | null
```

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by the others, there is no syntactic way to achieve this via a type guard. I think the way to solve such an issue as intended by the TypeScript developers is to use new variables or reassignments with narrowed types:

```
function assertData(d: Data | null): Data {
  if (d === null)
    throw new Error("Invalid data");
  return d;
}

class C {
  data: Data | null;

  public doA() {
    const data = assertData(this.data);
    /* do what you want with data instead of this.data */
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do the reassignment with `this.data` instead, which should be enough to narrow the type in the subsequent code:

```
class C {
  data: Data | null;

  public doA() {
    this.data = assertData(this.data);
    /* … */
  }
}
```

This also has the advantage of being more type safe than a type guard as type guards allow you to "lie" about the type of a variable while this is not possible here.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you want, but you can add an [is annotation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html) to use the function with an `if` condition:

```
type Data = string;
function assertData(d: Data | null): d is Data {
  if (d == null)
    throw new Error("Invalid data");
  return true;
}
// Use
let foo: Data | null = null;
if (assertData(foo)) {
  foo.toUpperCase(); // inferred to be Data
}
```

Comment: The usage OP is looking for is a type guard without the `if`, basically tell the compiler after this function call the argument is always of a certain type. `let foo: Data | null = null;
assertData(foo);
foo // should be Data but is still Data | null 
`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir that is exactly how it works. I'ved added your code so there is no confusion 

Comment: @basarat Really? AFAICT tsc still says 'Object may be null' if I try to use `foo`.  Is your function different from the one called `validData` in the OP, or are you saying that it already behaves like I wanted?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20interface%20Data%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0Afunction%20assertData(d%3A%20Data%20%7C%20null)%3A%20d%20is%20Data%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(d%20%3D%3D%3D%20null)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%22Invalid%20data%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0A%7D%0A%2F%2F%20Use%20%0Alet%20foo%3A%20Data%20%7C%20null%20%3D%20null%3B%20%0AassertData(foo)%3B%20%0Aconsole.log(foo.x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20inferred%20to%20be%20Data

Comment: @basarat and type guards generally don't  appear to work like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Data%20%7B%20d%3A%20number%20%7D%0Ainterface%20Data2%20%7B%20d2%3A%20number%20%7D%0Afunction%20assertData(d%3A%20Data%20%7C%20Data2)%3A%20d%20is%20Data%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20((d%20as%20Data).d%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%22Invalid%20data%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Adeclare%20let%20foo%3A%20Data%20%7C%20Data2%3B%0AassertData(foo)%3B%0Afoo.d2

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir my bad. Fixed 

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, that's the most convenient (currently possible) way.

```
function validData(d: Data | null): d is Data {
  if (d === null) {
    throw new Error("Invalid data");
  }

  return d !== null;
}

class C {
  data: Data | null;

  public doA() {
    if (!validData(this.data)) return;

    /* typeof this.data equals Data now */
    /* … */
  }

  public doB() {
    if (!validData(this.data)) return;

    /* typeof this.data equals Data now */
    /* … */
  }
}
```