# Encapsulate Type Guards into Functions

Tags: typescript

Is there anyway to encapsulate a type guard within a function as defined below?

```
function assertArray(value: any): void {
  if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
    throw "Not an array"
  }
}

// Doesn't work
function example1(value: string | []) {
  assertArray(value)
  return value.join('')
}

// But this works
function example2(value: string | []) {
  if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
    throw "Not an array"
  }
  return value.join('')
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoEEtbICeAFAG7IA2IGAXCmEQJT1lwwAmiA3gLABQiRDGCISAQnyEiAOhiopxclRpMmPAUKFQAFljgB3RACIAcnCgMUBYsc2IAvgKf8BAejeIAInAyowAOSWBnBYANYCoJCwCIgYAB7IALYADpQYAIzK1HSIqFBYMGAA5ogAPogA2gC66nyCKOjYeDakFDlM9lgYUCBYSO00MgBW7GAkAQGd-C7ungBCIJa68ogh4aiR4NDwSAnJaRgATNk09PmFJeVVtRoNImKSrXIKracYandaiLr6RmYWKzIVp2BouITdXr9RCDDAjMYTKbOIA)

The use cases is rather simple. I want to have runtime assertions, and I'd like to encapsulate the logic without having to return new variables. I know I could `const x = assertArray(y)`, but why can't I just `assertArray(y)`?

Comment: You can: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I write a type guard that throws exceptions instead of returning booleans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685977/can-i-write-a-type-guard-that-throws-exceptions-instead-of-returning-booleans)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using at least Typescript 3.7, you can create assertion functions:

```js
function assertArray(value: any): asserts value is any[] {
  if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
    throw "Not an array"
  }
}

function example1(value: string | []) {
  assertArray(value)
  return value.join('')
}
```